# Payment integration in react native with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, payment, paytm

I want to integrate payment processing in my react native app. I tried to do so with RN's webview but webview doesn't renders on web platform.
I want to read the response from the server too.
Please suggest me an easy way to either use Web-linking or something else to render the payment page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a payment gateway. A suggestion to start with would be [Stripe](https://stripe.com/)

Comment: I know I need to add payment gateway but I don't want to use webview....can u suggest me an alternative which should work for web tioo